# Storing bullets in my mongoDB database

Tags: android, mongodb

i am storing my coupons in my mongodb database now i want to store terms and conditions field in my database such that when i show any coupon's terms and conditions on either (Website/Android app) i want to show some points with bullets. Now i don't know how to store bullet character in my database and then how to parse them on my front end side both (Website/Android app) can anyone please tell me how mobile apps or websites achieve this type of functionality where they store data with some special characters like (/n, /t, bullets) and parse them on their front end.

Sorry if you think this answer is vague but i just want to get an idea about how should i store it in my DB,for worst case scenario what i think is to take any character like "/b" and put it in my database like for example see below line

> /b I Love you katie.

and then when i will parse my terms and conditions field on my front end then will put a bullet in place of /b in my front end on both (Website/Android) so final result on my front end would be

- I Love you katie.

Please tell me if i am thinking it in wrong direction or if you think your approach is better then mine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mongodb; you are really just asking how to store formatted text in a database, and the most common answer is to store text with markup.  There are a million different kinds of markup and a million different libraries for interpreting markup for presentation in your app.

Comment: @antlersoft so my approach would be right coz as i will parse it on my front end side and where i will get /b i will put bullet in place of it ??